# Google Cloud Endpoints and JWT

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an API based on Google Cloud Endpoints and I want to use JWT (Json Web Tokens) for authorization. I can set Authorization header for every request which contains token and it works correctly. I know that Endpoints uses this header for Oauth2 and here is my question. Is it correct to use Authorization header for custom token? GAE logs:

```
D 12:38:44.375 Checking for id_token.
D 12:38:44.376 id_token verification failed: Unexpected encryption algorithm: u'HS256'
D 12:38:44.376 Checking for oauth token.
D 12:38:44.384 Oauth framework user didn't match oauth token user.
```

It looks like GAE tries to read this token as oauth token and it is not good, right? Maybe I should send my token in URL? Something like app-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/my_app/v1/users/get?jwt=TOKEN. Maybe I shouldn't use JWT with Google Cloud Endpoints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These messages are due to the endpoints library attempting to automatically determine the user from the `Authorization` header so that it can provide `endpoints.get_current_user` ([source](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/lib/endpoints-1.0/endpoints/users_id_token.py#95)). It can do this automatically when the `Authorization` header contains a Bearer token that is a valid Google OAuth2 access token or an Android ID token.

Simply put, this is not an error, it's just not able to *automatically* process your Authorization header. No big deal since you're going with your own via JWT.

For JWTs, you can still use the `Authorization` header and validate the JWT yourself using `PyJWT` (to install third-party packages, see [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27?hl=en#vendoring)).

Here's a complete sample:

```py
import logging

import endpoints
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import message_types
from protorpc import remote

import jwt


class TestMessage(messages.Message):
    message = messages.StringField(1)


@endpoints.api(name='example', version='v1')
class ExampleApi(remote.Service):
    @endpoints.method(message_types.VoidMessage, TestMessage, http_method='GET')
    def auth(self, unused_request):

        # Get the HTTP Authorization header.
        auth_header = self.request_state.headers.get('authorization')
        if not auth_header:
            raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException("No authorization header.")

        # Get the encoded jwt token.
        auth_token = auth_header.split(' ').pop()

        # Decode and verify the token
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(auth_token, 'secret')
            # Do your own check here.
            logging.info(payload)
        except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
            raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException("Token validation failed.")

        return TestMessage(message='OK')


app = endpoints.api_server([ExampleApi])
```

You can test this with a self-generated jwt token:

```
$ python -c "import jwt; print jwt.encode({'some': 'data'}, 'secret')"
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzb21lIjoiZGF0YSJ9.g1aG08iQyPPwCTJHCxRrkKoYmLiHbBNdarcBQkCPMG4
```

Then use [httpie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie) to make a request:

```
$ http GET :8080/_ah/api/example/v1/auth Authorization:'Token eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzb21lIjoiZGF0YSJ9.g1aG08iQyPPwCTJHCxRrkKoYmLiHbBNdarcBQkCPMG4'
```

If you don't like seeing the endpoints logs about not being able to validate the token every time, you can use your own header, like `X-Auth`.