# Does Google Endpoint Authenticated Call Required Google Account?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I've been reading Google Documentation for Google Cloud Endpoint for a while but I can't still find specific solution/example for a scenario:

- App does **not** require Google Account (Authentication using custom or via Facebook)

How can I verify from GCE that the request really comes from my android, ios and web clients?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810378/

Comment: At least that is the answer for custom authentication that gets injected into your endpoint methods. If you want to have something more trivial you could inject the headers into your methods an check for an auth header.